# Difference between async/ and bulk/async in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I need to override my REST API endpoints to async and faced the issue that I don't understand the difference between asynchronous endpoints in

> https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/use-rest/asynchronous-web-endpoints/

and bulk endpoints in

> https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/use-rest/bulk-endpoints/

As I see they are working in the same way via a queue, could someone explain the difference or probably give a "right" way to create async endpoints from my REST API endpoints?

Answer (score 2):

The right way depends on what you want to override, but to answer your difference query, asynchronous web endpoints takes a single object as a request payload, e.g.

```json
{
  "product": {
    "price": 29
  }
}
```

Bulk endpoints takes multiple objects in an array as a request payload, e.g.

```json
[
  {
    "product": {
      "sku": "TEST_1"
      "price": 29
    }
  }, {
    "product": {
      "sku": "TEST_2"
      "price": 39
    }
  }
]
```

Hope thats clears the difference for you.